# Vue.js start pace.js on each component loading?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a  vue app like this:

```js
Vue.component('navigation', Navigation)
Vue.component('create', Create)
Vue.component('how', How)
Vue.component('about', About)
Vue.component('youtube', Youtube)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentView: 'create'
    },
    mounted() {
        pace.start()
    }
})
```

So what I want to achieve is for pace to start while a component is loading and stop it when it is finished loading that component, however, pace is not being started. Am I not doing it properly here?

Comment: You don't define `pace` in the code you've shared.

Comment: import pace from 'pace-js'; it's at the top of the page

Comment: Try `pace.restart()` instead of `pace.start()`

Comment: You should try to always include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) whenever asking for debugging help.

Comment: pace.restart doesn't do it either

Comment: `mounted()` is part of the app, it isn't inherited down into the components. As written it should be being called once when the app is mounted. Look at https://012.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mixins for a possible solution.